# When I press the space bar in the Leksah source editor, nothing happens. What packages do I lack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform, leksah

I'm going to retry learning Haskell again... So I apt-get installed leksah, ghc, quickcheck, and cabal-install. It didn't work right from the start, this is why I had to install cabal-install and quickcheck. But now the welcoming `Main.hs` Helloworld compiles fine, and runs fine. ( It's a really nice hand shake for beginners I must admit I appreciate )

However I'm facing some really strange problem. When I press the space bar in the Leksah source editor, nothing happens.

For example it won't let me enter `type MyType = Int` I would be stuck at the end of the word type... and if I continue the letters after the space, it would happend MyType to type giving me: `typeMyType`

If I define a function, it's not possible to insert any space in between elements

```
test_swap::[a]->[a]
test_swap(w1:w2:ws)=w2:w1:ws
test_swap(ws)=ws
```

I suspect that I am missing some package to install. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, with fluxbox, I have multiple keybindings but all other applications lives with it well and currently I use my space bar between each word in chromium. I have read that the Leksah editor uses gtk, but ubuntu unity uses parts of gtk/gnome so I should have gtk ok... but maybe I am missing a tiny bit...

I don't know. How could I know/guess what I am missing ?

Comment: It seems you have to write your own polymorphic monad that will hold your space problem inside.

Comment: I'd personally suggest not to use an IDE for now. When you're still learning Haskell, you're not gonna need one anyway (a decent editor will do), and so far I've found that Leksah was far more trouble than it's worth (maybe I'm doing something wrong, but hand editing cabal files was much easier for me til now. And ghci, runhaskell and ghc --make will probably do for a long time as well).

Comment: @Cubic, I was thinking about that this morning. Glad you confirm it is sufficient.

Comment: A good opportunity to start learning EMACS or VIM :P

Comment: Yep, I'll keep investing in vim, I'm into it for a few months now. emacs really didn't please me :-)

Comment: I'm going to agree with the other commenters: Leksah is more trouble than it is worth. I haven't figured out how to get any of its features to work. But I am going to throw GEdit out there as a possible alternative, especially with the smart-highlighting plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Gtk-related problem that occurs only for specific keyboard layouts. It happens with other applications such as Rhythmbox or Codeblocks.

In Ubuntu, you can fix this by switching the default keyboard layout "French (alternative)" to "French (France)" (see this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hal/+bug/451258).

Alternatively, you can add this option to your keyboard map:

```
setxkbmap -option nbsp:none
```